# Select multiple images and store their path. MSAccess - VBA

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have a database where my client creates an inspection record with multiple pictures attached to each inspection.

So far we've stored the pictures in the database itself using the attachment field. The only problem is that we are now approaching the 2Gb limit.

For this reason I am trying to link the pictures to the record instead. I created a new table called `Pictures` with 3 fields: PK `AutoID`, FK `PONumber`, `Path`.

I managed to get a button to insert the path into the table, the only problem is that it doesn't loop through the selection in the FileDialog, creating new records for each path.

***UPDATE*** I created a new form just to add the pictures. The form is linked to the table Pictures, so now i only need to make the sub loop through the user selection and store the path in the Path field, adding a new record for each path, but keeping the same PONumber so it can be linked to the Load table.

This is the code I am using for the button:

```
Private Sub PictureSelector_Click()

   Dim fDialog As FileDialog
   Dim varFile As Variant

   ' Set up the File Dialog.
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fDialog
      ' Allow user to make multiple selections in dialog box
      .AllowMultiSelect = True
      ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select one or more files"
      'Set the starting folder.
      .InitialFileName = "Q:\"
      'Show only graphic/image type files.
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Images", "*.jpg; *.jpeg", 1

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If fDialog.Show Then

        For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
           Path = varFile  
        Next varFile

      End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This is the relationship diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGXGW.jpg

Comment: I can't see any code that writes the information to the table, so it's not possible to try to reproduce your problem. Just based on the code we see, I'd say you're getting only the last selected entry? You need to process each `Path` within the `For Each` loop.

Comment: Path is also the name of the control textbox in the form, linked to the table. Could you elaborate please? I'm fairly new to VBA. and yes i do get only the last selected item

Comment: VBA is much better at guessing what the person writing the code wants than some other languages, but if there isn't a clear choice it may make the wrong one. For me, it looks like `Path` is a (`String`) variable, so it's not obvious to me that this is a control on the form (it's not even clear from the question that you're working with a form - you only mention a table). If VBA is recognizing `Path` correctly, then you probably need to change the *record* being shown in the form, each time through the loop. Same as if you were filling in the information manually.

Comment: Would be a good idea to [edit] this information into the question... So, would you expect all the file paths to be in this one field, concatenated into a string separated by, for example, a comma or semi-colon? Or should you have an entry for each path?

Comment: Always a good idea to complete your design decisions before starting to code... This is something you need to decide. Personally, yes, I'd have one PK entry + each entry that belongs to it. Not sure whether the FK entry is required since I have no idea about the entire data base...

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this code:

```
Private Sub UploadPicture_Click()

   Dim fDialog As FileDialog
   Dim varFile As Variant
   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Pictures")
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fDialog
      .AllowMultiSelect = True
      .Title = "Please select one or more files"
      .InitialFileName = "Q:\"
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Images", "*.jpg; *.jpeg", 1

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If fDialog.Show Then

      For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
      rs.AddNew
      rs!PONumber = Me.PONumber
      rs!Path = varFile
      rs.Update

    Next varFile

    End If
    End With
End Sub
```